# Decompressing requests using ServiceStack within a .Net Core Alpine container

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, servicestack, alpine-linux

I'm building a containerized micro-service that uses ServiceStack running with .Net Core on the ASPNET Core Alpine docker image. I want to be able receive compressed requests containing Gzipped JSON within the request body, have the request decompressed before it hits ServiceStack so that the request DTO is populated based on the decompressed JSON data.

So far I have tried rolling my own middle-ware to do this, but my request DTO is still populated with Nulls. I have also tried using Anemonis.AspNetCore.RequestDecompression middleware, with the same result. I'm now wondering if the middle-ware is not being called before ServiceStack receives the request, or even not being called at all.

Using the Anemonis middle-ware, my Startup.cs initializes the middle-ware as such:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseRequestDecompression();

    app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost
    {
        AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration),
    });

    //...
}
```

With decompression provided within ConfigureServices:

```
public new void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    services.AddRequestDecompression(o =>
    {
        o.Providers.Add<DeflateDecompressionProvider>();
        o.Providers.Add<GzipDecompressionProvider>();
        o.Providers.Add<BrotliDecompressionProvider>();
    });

    //...
}
```

And for further detail, ServiceStack service model and interface as usual:

```
[Route("/sample/full", "POST")]
public class SampleFull : IReturn<SampleResponse>
{
    public long code { get; set; }
    public SampleData[] data { get; set; }
}

public class SampleData
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public string field2 { get; set; }
}

public class SampleService : Service
{
    public object Post(SampleFull request)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do some processing

            return new SampleResponse()
            {
                // Response details
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new SampleResponse()
            {
                // Error details
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Using Postman to test, Content-Encoding = gzip, with a gzipped file as the request body, when `Post(SampleFull request)` is called, `request` is populated with null values for both `code` and `data`.

Has anyone been able to get this working? I'm now thinking that I could be missing a library/package within the ASPNET Core Alpine container.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question as I have finally found the issue. As it turns out, by default, Postman will send a Content-Type header with a value of application/octet-stream when you select to send a binary file as the request body. This header is hidden by default, and you can't overwrite it, but you can disable it and add your own Content-Type header with a value of application/json, which then allows ServiceStack to correctly populate it's request DTO. Solved.